# detect previous url in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, url

Is there a way to detect the previous URL that user visited before arrive on my website using javascript or jQuery?

I hope it can be possible avoid using PHP

Comment: You should refer to the [w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/) for what the use cases are for being able to retrieve that information (whether on the server or on the browser) and what the values might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to get the previous URL when the user directly enters the new URL in the browser without clicking a link. **This is not possible in PHP or JavaScript.** It would be a significant and quite unnecessary security risk, so browsers will refuse to send it. You can only get it through the referrer if the user clicked a link on the previous website that redirected them to yours.

Frankly, there should be no reason for the new website to know about the previous one unless the user was *referred* from the previous URL by clicking a link.

Comment: what you mean _"because it would be a huge security risk"_ please can you explain better in your answer?

Comment: I mean that websites could track you unwillingly even though this feature would provide no applicable value. The website you just happened to previously be on is in no way relevant to the new one.

Comment: So how commonly people do it? because I know that other websites can track the previous page

Comment: They don't. If anything, they track a referrer which is only present when people click a link on the previous page to be redirected to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.referrer
```

I think is the most common one. There is also the history api

Comment: seem to does not work for me... I'm using Chrome on Windows